# I want to add contact form 7 data to zoho crm with custom code in wordpress. I tried but not find any solution

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, zoho

I already added the code on my function.php file by applying zoho crm api but the data is not transferring on ZOHO crm.

I called the data through the access token provided by Zoho crm, then i create API v2 of web API and generate client id and client secret. I don't know where i am making error

Please check and update me where i am making mistake

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent','brainium_cf7_api_sender');

function brainium_cf7_api_sender(){
    
    $title = $contact_form->title;

         if( $title === 'Contact form 1') {
           $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if( $submission ){
          $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

          $first_name = $posted_data['first-name'];
          $last_name = $posted_data['last-name'];
          $email = $posted_data['your-email'];
          $phone = $posted_data['Phone-no'];
          $message = $posted_data['your-message'];
          $budget = $posted_data['budget'];
          $checkbox = $posted_data['checkbox-993'];

                    $auth = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
                    $refreshToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
                    //get the last date and time of refresh token generation
                    
                    //get the access token
                    $url = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token";
                    $query = "refresh_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=refresh_token";
                    
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    //get the token from the JSON in result
                    $accessToken =  json_decode($result, true);
                    //echo ($accessToken['access_token']); 
                    //die();        
                    
                    $data = array("First_Name"=>$first_name, "Last_Name"=>$last_name, "Email"=>$email, "Phone"=>$phone, "Description"=>($message), "Budget"  => $budget, 'Subscribed_Newsletter' => $checkbox, "Lead_Date"=>$zoho_date, '$gclid'=>$zc_gad);
                    //$data = json_encode($data);
                    
                    $encodedData = array();
                    $encodedData['data'][0] = $data;
                    
                    //var_dump($data);
                    //echo(json_encode($encodedData));
                    //die();
                    //che


                    $url ="https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads";
                    $headers = array(
                                        'Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken '.$accessToken['access_token'],
                                        'Content-Type:application/json'
                                    );

                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($encodedData));
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    //echo $result;
                    /**** End zoho CRM ****/
                    $success = true;
                    $msg = 'Done';
                    
                    $leadSaving = print_r($result, true);
                    $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . $email;
                    $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . "request quote";
                    file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", $leadSaving, FILE_APPEND);
                    file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", "\r\n\r\n", FILE_APPEND);      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you added to your functions.php so that people can help.

Comment: Please check now..i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

I tried and getting the following SUCCESS response

```
{"data":[{"code":"SUCCESS","details":{"Modified_Time":"2022-07-27T17:28:36+05:30","Modified_By":{"name":"Sourav Sinha","id":"1153488000000068001"},"Created_Time":"2022-07-27T17:28:36+05:30","id":"1153488000046560019","Created_By":{"name":"Sourav Sinha","id":"1153488000000068001"}},"message":"record added","status":"success"}]}
youremail@test.com
request quote
```

Comment: But when i adding then my data is not submitting to zoho crm...i don't know what is the exact problem

Comment: I tested using static values, You make sure if all the user input values are received before send to zoho API.

Comment: yes all the entered user input value on contact form received

Comment: hi can you please tell once from where you tested the code...with contact form 7 wordpress or normal making localhost php

Comment: Please check the code in following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73148408/6092847

Comment: I tried in localhost php

Comment: hi i tried to run your code but caught the error

Comment: Warning: Undefined variable $zoho_date in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\data.php on line 32

Warning: Undefined variable $zc_gad in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\data.php on line 32

Comment: can you please help me how to do it with contact form 7 wordpress plugin

Comment: In your contact form 7 code, the following variables are not assigned any value, that could also cause issue, you can set any static values in your code and try.
`$zoho_date, $zc_gad`

Comment: i tried, i removed $zoho_date, $zc_gad these variables but still not work with my contact form 7...can you please check once the code if it is written correctly or not

Comment: Can you share the lead-zoho-entry-status.txt log file from your contact form 7 entry

Comment: yes you can check

Comment: {"code":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","details":{},"message":"Authentication failed","status":"error"}

finaltest@gmail.com
request quote

{"code":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","details":{},"message":"Authentication failed","status":"error"}

ss@gmail.com
request quote

Comment: can you send me your admin contact form field codes

Comment: First name- [first-name]
Last name- [last-name]
Your email- [your-email]
Phone No- [Phone-no]
Your message-[your-message]   Budget- [budget]  [checkbox-194]

Comment: Sorry, you sent invalid field, you send me the form fields those you can see in "Form" tab, the fields you sent can't generate contact form in frontend.

Comment: what exactly you want...can you please specify?

Comment: <label> First name
    [text* first-name] </label>

<label> Last name
    [text* last-name] </label>

<label> Your email
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Phone No
   [text* Phone-no]</label>

<label> Your message (optional)
    [textarea your-message] </label>

<label> Budget
   [text* budget]</label>

[checkbox checkbox-194 use_label_element "I want to subscribe"]

[submit "Submit"]

Comment: I generated it though contact form7 plugin you can also check code below-

Comment: You need to make changes in two places in your code, check the following image for reference
[link](https://snipboard.io/fUSTtv.jpg)

Comment: {"code":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","details":{},"message":"Authentication failed","status":"error"}

ffg@gmail.com
request quote

{"code":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","details":{},"message":"Authentication failed","status":"error"}

aad@gmail.com
request quote

Comment: still the same erro

Comment: function brainium_cf7_api_sender($contact_form){

$checkbox = $posted_data['checkbox-194'][0];

Comment: Make sure the **auth** and **refreshToken** values are correct.

Comment: i am a little bit confused, if everything right in local host php then how can auth and refreshtoken wrong in contact form7 implementation

Comment: I tried in my local contact form 7, it worked for me.

Comment: can you please share me the code

Comment: This is the code i tried
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73156239/6092847

Comment: thank you so much..it is working now...can you please one last thing tell what should be the code for upload field

Comment: There is a button called **file** in the **Form** tab, which can be used for upload.

Comment: yes that i know but, $posted_data['checkbox-194'][0] there mention checkbox ..so my question how to get posted data of upload field there

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about zoho upload file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$first_name = 'first-name';
$last_name = 'last-name';
$email = 'youremail@test.com';
$phone = '9876543210';
$message = 'your-message';
$budget = '1000';
$checkbox = '1';

          $auth = 'fa738eaef1becee890f8935f65169e99';
          $refreshToken = "1000.3c0d5bb96a00e9438d132d94a316a72b.2d5261b7e33c42614c08f1bd4e9a0f1a";
          //get the last date and time of refresh token generation
          
          //get the access token
          $url = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token";
          $query = "refresh_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=refresh_token";
          
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
          $result = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          //get the token from the JSON in result
          $accessToken =  json_decode($result, true);
          //echo ($accessToken['access_token']); 
          //die();        
          
          $data = array("First_Name"=>$first_name, "Last_Name"=>$last_name, "Email"=>$email, "Phone"=>$phone, "Description"=>($message), "Budget"  => $budget, 'Subscribed_Newsletter' => $checkbox, "Lead_Date"=>$zoho_date, '$gclid'=>$zc_gad);
          //$data = json_encode($data);
          
          $encodedData = array();
          $encodedData['data'][0] = $data;
          
          //var_dump($data);
          //echo(json_encode($encodedData));
          //die();
          //che


          $url ="https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads";
          $headers = array(
                              'Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken '.$accessToken['access_token'],
                              'Content-Type:application/json'
                          );

          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($encodedData));
          $result = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          //echo $result;
          /**** End zoho CRM ****/
          $success = true;
          $msg = 'Done';
          
          $leadSaving = print_r($result, true);
          $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . $email;
          $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . "request quote";
          file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", $leadSaving, FILE_APPEND);
          file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", "\r\n\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code used in functions.php file

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent','brainium_cf7_api_sender');
function brainium_cf7_api_sender($contact_form){
    $title = $contact_form->title;

    if( $title === 'Contact form 1') {
       $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if( $submission ){
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

            $first_name = $posted_data['first-name'];
            $last_name = $posted_data['last-name'];
            $email = $posted_data['your-email'];
            $phone = $posted_data['Phone-no'];
            $message = $posted_data['your-message'];
            $budget = $posted_data['budget'];
            $checkbox = $posted_data['checkbox-194'][0];

            $auth = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
            $refreshToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
            //get the last date and time of refresh token generation
            
            //get the access token
            $url = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token";
            $query = "refresh_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=refresh_token";
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            //get the token from the JSON in result
            $accessToken =  json_decode($result, true);
            //echo ($accessToken['access_token']); 
            //die();        
            
            $data = array("First_Name"=>$first_name, "Last_Name"=>$last_name, "Email"=>$email, "Phone"=>$phone, "Description"=>($message), "Budget"  => $budget, 'Subscribed_Newsletter' => $checkbox, "Lead_Date"=>$zoho_date, '$gclid'=>$zc_gad);
            //$data = json_encode($data);
            
            $encodedData = array();
            $encodedData['data'][0] = $data;
            
            //var_dump($data);
            //echo(json_encode($encodedData));
            //die();
            //che


            $url ="https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads";
            $headers = array(
                                'Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken '.$accessToken['access_token'],
                                'Content-Type:application/json'
                            );

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($encodedData));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            //echo $result;
            // End zoho CRM
            $success = true;
            $msg = 'Done';
            
            $leadSaving = print_r($result, true);
            $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . $email;
            $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . "request quote";
            file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", $leadSaving, FILE_APPEND);
            file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", "\r\n\r\n", FILE_APPEND); 
        }
    } 
}
```